# Javascript: How to rearrange a json

Tags: javascript, json

I wish to rearrange a json using javascript. The first json have one array named ids and have columns named `identifier.id`, `id` and `address`. I want to create an array using javascript where have an array to group by the same identifiers.id, the name of this array is identifiers where have a column named `identifier.id` and I want to include inside identifiers array a second array named registrations where have the columns id and address.

This is the json I have:

```
"ids": [
{
  "id": "27675548",
  "identifier.id": "156473847",
  "address": "Rua Brasilia, 23232, Sao Benedito - BH"
},
{
  "id": "27675569",
  "identifier.id": "156473847",
  "address": "Rua Brasilia, 11, Sao Benedito - BH"
}
```

And this is the json I want to achieve:

```
 "identifiers":[
{
  "identifier.id":"156473847",
  "registrations":[
    {
      "id": "27675548",
      "address": "Rua Brasilia, 23232, Sao Benedito - BH"
    },
    {
      "id": "27675569",
      "address": "Rua Brasilia, 11, Sao Benedito - BH"
    }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the first json has two positions, but the two positions shows the same value for identifier.id and the second json group the same value of the identifier.id in an array and inside this arrays have other array to store the columns id and address.

Is this possible using Javascript?

Comment: It is possible, you probably want to use the function `reduce`.

Comment: @sjahan - `reduce` wouldn't be a good choice for tackling the above.

Comment: Your first step, if you really have *JSON*, is to parse it, at which point you don't have JSON anymore. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i ve created this two jsons but i dont know how to convert the first one to second one

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why wouldn't it be good? I admit I probably often use too much `reduce` to make something with a new shape, and sometimes, it does not really "reduce"... Although, i'd like to understand why there, it wouldn't be good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `rearrange` function that will group objects by specified `groupBy` key into specified collection `collectionName`:

```js
function rearrange(data, groupBy, collectionName) {
    return { 
        identifiers: Object.values(data.ids.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            if(!acc[cur[groupBy]]) {
                acc[cur[groupBy]] = {
                    [groupBy]: cur[groupBy],
                    [collectionName]: []
                }
            }
            const obj = Object.assign({}, cur);
            delete obj[groupBy]
            acc[cur[groupBy]][collectionName].push(obj);
            return acc;
        }, {}))
    };
}

const data = {
    "ids": [
        {
          "id": "27675548",
          "identifier.id": "156473847",
          "address": "Rua Brasilia, 23232, Sao Benedito - BH"
        },
        {
          "id": "27675569",
          "identifier.id": "156473847",
          "address": "Rua Brasilia, 11, Sao Benedito - BH"
        },
        {
          "id": "27675561",
          "identifier.id": "156473848",
          "address": "Rua Brasilia, 12, Sao Benedito - XX"
        }
    ]
};

console.log(rearrange(data, 'identifier.id', 'registrations'));
```

It works the following way:

1. Define map, where key is value of `groupBy` property in the objects that you want to group
2. Iterate over objects and check if the key is presented in the map
3. If key does not exist, create a new group with shared key and collection of objects that share it.
4. Copy all properties of object, except defined in `groupBy`, to new object and put it to relevant group.
5. Once iteration is over, take the values of the map and put them to `identifiers` property of new JavaScript object to be returned.

*I added one more item into your test object to demonstrate multiple groups :)*

You can read more about `Array.prototype.reduce` function and it's parameters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Just one thing i didnt understand what is acc and cur ?

Comment: @Taniguchi.sales : acc - accumulator, the object that is bypassed to each iteration, may be modified and is used as temporary storage. cur - current value, the item that you are currently working with in this function execution.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, I would personally use `reduce` to create another object where I would use `identifier.id` as the key for each object to check if the ID already exists or not (to prevent a `find` on each iteration).

Then I would use `Object.values` to get only the array of the values and getting rid of the keys that you don't want: you just want the array of values.

Feel free to add any comment if this is not clear or can be improved!

```js
const ids = [
{
  "id": "27675548",
  "identifier.id": "156473847",
  "address": "Rua Brasilia, 23232, Sao Benedito - BH"
},
{
  "id": "27675569",
  "identifier.id": "156473847",
  "address": "Rua Brasilia, 11, Sao Benedito - BH"
}];

const result = Object.values(ids.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const identifier = item["identifier.id"];
  if(!acc[identifier]) acc[identifier] = { "identifier.id": identifier, "registrations": []};
  acc[identifier].registrations.push({id: item.id, address: item.address});
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```